# Google App Script to find a value in particular column only

Tags: google-apps-script

I found below script from one of the Stackoverflow posts.. it is almost match my requirement but I need few changes... like.. I don't want to replace, I only want it to find my value in a particular column and also want it to go to that cell when it finds the value. Can someone help me out?

also.. I want a shortcut key to run the macro... instead of the sheet's Ctrl+F.. I want it to display the search prompt when I give Ctrl+F... is it possible??

```
function findingReplacing()
{
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Search String", "Please enter desired search string", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK).getResponseText();
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D:D');
  var rngA = rng.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    if(rngA[i][0]==s)
    {
      rngA
```

Comment: Use text finder. Google or search here for relevant posts.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Marios, the easiest way is to use [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) in your selected range.

**Here is a sample code:**

```
function findingAndSelect()
{
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Search String", "Please enter desired search string",      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK).getResponseText();
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
  Logger.log(s);
  // Creates  a text finder for the range.
  var textFinder = rng.createTextFinder(s);
  textFinder.matchEntireCell(true);
  textFinder.matchCase(false);

  // Returns the first occurrence of the string.
  var result = textFinder.findAll();
  if (result.length == 0){
    /* string not found */
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Search String", "String not found",SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }else{
    result.forEach((range) => { range.setBackground('#d5f5df');});
  }

}
```

**How to use?**

1. **Select the entire column** where you want to do the search.
2. **Enter the string** to be search.
3. Click **OK**.

**What it does?**

1. Ask for a string to be search.
2. Get active range/ selected range where to look for the string (in your case the whole column should be selected).
3. Create a text finder and look for the input string.
4. Check if the string was found. Then change the background color of all ranges where the string was found

**Additional Information:**

You can also specify the search preference you want in your text finder. Please check [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) to see available methods.

If you want to match the string to the entire cell, You can use [matchEntireCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#matchentirecellmatchentirecell) and set to true.

```
// Match the entire content of a cell.
textFinder.matchEntireCell(true);
```

If you want to match the string based on its case, you can use [matchCase()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#matchcasematchcase) and set to true.

```
// Match the search text's case exactly
textFinder.matchCase(true);
```

---

### **Output:**

[image]

---

## [Importing functions as macros](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros#importing_functions_as_macros)

1. In the Google Sheets UI, select Tools > Macros > Import.
2. Select a function form the list presented and then click Add function.
3. Select clear to close the dialog.
4. Select Tools > Macros > Manage macros.
5. Locate the function you just imported in the list. Assign a unique keyboard shortcut to the macro. You can also change the macro name here; the name defaults to the name of the function.
6. Click Update to save the macro configuration.

**Note:** You can link a macro to a keyboard shortcut in the form `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Number`

Comment: Hi Ron, one more thing... it finds the first occurrence, but in my column I have duplicate values.. and I want it to take it to each cell where the value is.. in this case.. how do I tweak the code?

Comment: It is not possible for `textFinder`. When an Apps Script function was executed successfully it will clear all the data based on scopes. I tried checking Apps Script [CacheService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#putkey,-value) but it can only save a string value in the cache. I was initially planning to create another function to call the `textFinder.findNext()` once i successfully save the `textFinder` in the cache from the `findingAndSelect()`.

Comment: One workaround I could suggest is to change the background color of all the matching cells when you call `findingAndSelect()`. If that will be fine with you, you just need to loop `textFinder.findNext()` and change each cells until it return a null

Comment: Hi Ron, Like I mentioned before.. I am not that good with Appscript... I am okay with the workaround, could you please help to add this code in your above given sample code?

Comment: I'm not sure why you prefer creating such function instead of just using CTRL+F to find a string, but if you insist please refer to the updated answer

Comment: Hi Ron, Thanks!! again.... I colleague is not using CTRL+F because it searches in entire sheet and not in a particular column... and everytime she opens the sheet she has to give range in Find function... she didn't wanted that... so asked me to help and find a script that would simply search in one column only

Comment: Actually, she can select the column where she wants to do the search first then use CTRL+F.

Comment: If you find this helpful, please consider accepting or up-voting the answer.

Comment: Really?? ....Anyways...thanks for sharing..